# Using Python to Iterate Through Large DEM

Tags: python, iteration, arcgis

I am trying to iterate through a large digital elevation model (DEM) and create new text files with its contents at increments of 4000 using Python.  Below is code for iterating through a file row by row, but I would like to increase the number of rows being written to a new file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read in File
df1 = pd.read_table('Large_DEM_File.txt', skiprows=6, chunksize=500)

df = pd.concat(df1)
rows = 320000
y= -1003.00
delta = 0.00025
linecount= 4001

#initialize counter
i = 0
while i <= rows:
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        filename = open(str(i)+'.txt','w')
        filename.write("ncols 136000\nrows 320000\nxllcorner 122\n")
        filename.write("yllcorner %.5f" %(y+rows*delta-(i+1)*delta))
        filename.write("\ncellsize 0.00025\nNODATA_value -9999\n")
        filename.write(row[0:4000+i])
        i += 4000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data and am a bit confused what you're trying to do, but does this get you what you want?

```
rows = 320000
y= -1003.00
delta = 0.00025

df_chunk_reader = pd.read_table('Large_DEM_File.txt', skiprows=6, chunksize=500)

for i,chunk in enumerate(df_chunk_reader):

    filename = open(str(i)+'.txt','wb')
    filename.write("ncols 136000\nrows 320000\nxllcorner 122\n")
    filename.write("yllcorner %.5f" %(y+rows*delta-(i+1)*delta))
    filename.write("\ncellsize 0.00025\nNODATA_value -9999\n")
    filename.write(chunk)
```

See here for more on processing dataframes by chunk:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: Enumerate is a great function, but it doesn't always work well with large data.  My ultimate goal is to iterate through large data (ascii DEM's) without storing the data, and segment the large data into more digestible memory for further computation.  I've heard xrange is a possible way, but I don't have much experience using that function.

Comment: the main difference between my code above and yours isn't enumerate, it's the processing by chunks. df_chunk_reader in my code is a generator (like xrange), but will yield a chunk of your dataset at a time. that way you can process the data however you want, chunk by chunk. the size of the chunks can be whatever you want, determined by the chunksize parameter.

Comment: in your question code, you also have df1 which is a generator which yields a chunk of your dataset at a time. but instead of processing it chunk by chunk, your code concatenates all the chunks together, then processes it line by line. If I understand your question correctly, you should instead just process it chunk by chunk like in my answer code above.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Unfortunately, I still run into memory errors "out of memory", and the script is unable to process the data.  As I am needing to process the DEM every 4,000 rows by 136,000 columns it runs into memory issues with some of the python functions.

Comment: Do you have to use 4,000 rows and 136,000 columns at a time? Or can you use fewer rows (e.g. chunksize = 500) at a time and still get correct results? Or if you need 4,000 rows, maybe consider only 1,000 columns at a time and loop through that process 136 times?

Comment: That may be a possibility.  How would I go about chunking the columns?